# SQL - Designing a Phone book database with Hierarchical model (master-client)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I just joined this site and this is my first question , I hope my question it's according to the StackOverflow question policy.

I'm designing a DB for Phone book which has the following abilities

- Contact have 2 types (Company or Person)->ContactType
- And I want each contact to have as many Emails, Phones Numbers, and Addresses as it wants.
- And I want to specify which Person works in which Company , so I can show not only a Company Contact detail but also list of its employees and their jobs in that Company and their Contacts (CoEmpJob table)

I have designed a db diagram which is shown in the link below, is it well structured or can I achieve what I want in some better way?

Thanks in advance.

[My Phone Book Design](http://i50.tinypic.com/2a83vyv.jpg)

Comment: Get a copy of "Data Model Resource Book". It has solutions for cases like that, fully documented. The phone book is I think 50 pages or so, with addresses etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the design stands, you're missing a few things, such as a Companies table and a ContactTypes table. There seems to be no foreign key in the CoEmpJob table linking to the Contacts table.

In the Phones table, I personally wouldn't use a prefix field (unless you wish to display contacts by phone prefix), in which case every phone number is guaranteed to be unique, in which case the PhoneNum field becomes the primary key and the PhoneID field is unnecessary - but you might have the case in which husband and wife are in the same database; whilst they almost certainly have different mobile numbers, they almost certainly share the same home phone number! In this case, your design is correct.

I don't know how many people have more than one address (I would think very few, if at all) which means that the fields of the Address table could be moved into the Contacts table.

(Added)
As regards the companies, if you *want to specify which Person works in which Company*, then you will need a companies table (missing) and a join table (CoEmpJob). In the real world, this design would also require more tables - a join table can show which contacts are connected to which companies and what their current jobs are, but people change jobs (and companies) and so such a design would not store any history. Also, it is customary to link people (employees) to a department - and it is possible that one person can be connected to more than one department at a time, meaning that you will need another join table. This can get very complicated - it depends on what you want.

Your comment suggests that you want to store company data in the contacts table - this is a very bad idea; they should be kept separate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Maybe it's better instead of ContactType field i put IsPerson as Boolean , And about CoEmpJob table yes it has 2 foreign key linking to Contacts table (CompanyID-> ContactID which IsPerson=False , CompanyEmployeeID-> ContactID which IsPerson=True).   My main question is about CoEmpJob table , can I achieve what I want or there is some better way?